# Subsetting pandas dataframe using several conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

All,

I need some help in subsetting a dataframe. It looks like this:

```
                                                          value1   value2
Ref_id           Date_upload       Date_download                              
03-492-9 2018-04-07 17:17:00 2018-05-10 19:06:03           59844   6950.0
01-782-8 2018-05-07 14:21:00 2018-05-10 19:06:10           59000   6500.0
01-782-8 2018-04-20 19:38:00 2018-05-11 20:06:18           36741  65000.0
73-80-12 2018-04-03 18:54:00 2018-05-10 19:06:23          127500  12500.0
73-80-12 2018-04-03 18:54:00 2018-05-11 19:06:28          174000   6199.0
```

I want to impose two conditions:

1. For every Ref_id: keep the row with the most recent date in **Date_upload**
2. For every Ref_id: similar as condition 1, but this time for **Date_download**

So, the result should be:

```
                                                          value1   value2
Ref_id           Date_upload       Date_download                              
03-492-9 2018-04-07 17:17:00 2018-05-10 19:06:03           59844   6950.0
01-782-8 2018-05-07 14:21:00 2018-05-10 19:06:10           59000   6500.0
73-80-12 2018-04-03 18:54:00 2018-05-11 19:06:28          174000   6199.0
```

Does anyone have a solution or some tips for me?

Comment: If you have a row where Date_download > a row with Date_upload, which row would you want to keep

Comment: For `01-782-8` most recent `Date_download` is `2018-05-11 20:06:18`. Why is that not in the output?